# Probability of Random Item Selection

Tags: probability, statistics

In a 15-piece batch there are 5 black balls and the 10 remaining balls are white. 3 balls are selected randomly. The batch is discarded if among the chosen ones at least one selected ball is white.

What is the probability of this?

I assume the random selection is based upon no replacements, as 3 balls are taken at one go.

Formula: $P(X=x) = C(n,x) p^x (1–p)^{n-x}$

The probability of selecting a white ball is given by $\tfrac{10}{15}$, hence $\tfrac{2}{3}$ should be white.

But how about the probability distribution for at least one single white ball selected out of 3?

Thanks to @lulu: $1 - (\tfrac{5}{15} * \tfrac{4}{14} * \tfrac{3}{13}$) or just $1 - \binom 53 \Big / \binom {15}3$

Comment: This is hard to follow.  I have $15$ of something (not sure what), and $5$ of those are dumbbells.  I take $3$ of the dumbbells (so what are the other $10$ objects for?) and then I ask if any of those $3$ are "incomplete"?  What's an incomplete dumbbell?

Comment: The problem @lulu is that I translated the task using google translator, so I rewrote it trying to give it more sense. Basically, out of 15 there are 5 items and the rest of the batch is empty, therefore 10 empty 'unused slots'? What I try to compute is out of 3 random selections, what is the probability of selecting at least 1 empty slot whilst the remaining 2 selections contain dumbbells.

Comment: Still confusing.  Are you asking this:  "You have $10$ white balls and $5$ black balls.  You select $3$ balls without replacement.  What is the probability that you have chosen exactly one black ball?"

Comment: Yes @lulu ! But instead of selecting exactly one black ball, out of the 3 balls there must be at least 1 white ball.

Comment: The task itself was really confusing to me too after translating it. Thinking in terms of balls makes it way easier @lulu

Comment: Ok, so you are asking:  "you have $10$ white balls and $5$ black balls, from which you draw $3$ balls without replacement.  What is the probability that you get at least one white ball?"  Yes?  If so, I'd post this version...the stuff about the dumbbells is unreadable.

Comment: To solve the ball problem, it's easier to compute the probability of getting $3$ black balls.  That's just $\binom 53 \Big / \binom {15}3$.  Now subtract from $1$.

Comment: You're using the wrong probability model in your question. Drawing 3 at once is equivalent to drawing one, then a second *without replacing the first* then a third *without replacing either of the first two*.